# How to cat multiple lines and delete existing contents

Tags: bash

I normally run a command like

```
cat <<EOF >> /path/to/file
some stuff
more stuff
EOF
```

However, this time, I want to overwrite the existing file and not append to it. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Change `>>` to `>`.

>> means append to file.

> means write file from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

To overwrite a file instead of appending to it you can use `>` instead of `>>`.